# ITextSharp: Set table cell border color

Tags: c#, itext

How do I set the border color of a table cell. here is the code i have:

```
// create and define table
var table = new PdfPTable(8);
table.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

//table.HeaderRows = 1;

// the cell object
PdfPCell cell;
var f = FontFactory.GetFont("Tahoma", 11, Font.BOLD);

cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Source Review", f));
cell.BorderColorLeft = new BaseColor(255, 255, 255);
cell.BorderColorRight = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(255, 255, 255);
table.AddCell(cell);
```

As you can see i am setting the color two different ways and neither way is working. When the table is rendered the border is always black. How can I fix this.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

When you set *individual* cell border properties you either need to set **all** border colors and widths individually, or explicitly set the [UseVariableBorders](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Rectangle.html#useVariableBorders) property to `true`. Try this example to see what I mean:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("test 1"));
cell.UseVariableBorders = true;
cell.BorderColorLeft = BaseColor.BLUE;
cell.BorderColorRight = BaseColor.ORANGE;
table.AddCell(cell);

cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("test 2"));
cell.BorderColorLeft = BaseColor.RED;
cell.BorderColorRight = BaseColor.GREEN;
cell.BorderColorTop = BaseColor.PINK;
cell.BorderColorBottom = BaseColor.YELLOW;
cell.BorderWidthLeft = 1f;
cell.BorderWidthRight = 1f;
cell.BorderWidthTop = 1f;
cell.BorderWidthBottom = 1f;
table.AddCell(cell);

cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("test 3"));
cell.BorderColor = BaseColor.GREEN;
table.AddCell(cell);
```