# How to change color of Table in itextsharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

I want to change my table border color, I am using iTextsharp library for generating pdf file.

> productsTable.DefaultCell.BorderColor= new CMYKColor(0f,0f,100f,0f);

When I use this line the border color not change.

So please anybody help that how to change my iTextsharp table border color?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9417054/itextsharp-set-table-cell-border-color

Answer (score 0):

add in ExportPDf function this code -

```
ProcuctsTable.Style.Add(\\add style here );
```