# Itextsharp fit width and give border

Tags: vb.net, itext

I am designing a table in pdf using itextsharp. I want to ask if anyone knows:

1. How to give border (*like color = silver, 1px, fit to width*) to
   header text?
2. How to make table fit to page width (*like 100%*)?

I am using vb.net

```
Protected Sub Create_Pdf_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Create_Pdf.Click
    Dim pdfDoc As New Document()
    Dim pdfWrite As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, New FileStream("D://PDF/myfile.pdf", FileMode.Create))
    pdfDoc.Open()
    pdfDoc.Add(New Paragraph("Here is header text"))
    Dim table As New PdfPTable(3)
    Dim cell As New PdfPCell(New Phrase("Header spanning 3 columns"))
    cell.Colspan = 3
    cell.HorizontalAlignment = 1

    table.AddCell(cell)
    table.AddCell("Col 1 Row 1")
    table.AddCell("Col 2 Row 1")
    table.AddCell("Col 3 Row 1")
    table.AddCell("Col 1 Row 2")
    table.AddCell("Col 2 Row 2")
    table.AddCell("Col 3 Row 2")
    pdfDoc.Add(table)
    pdfDoc.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

When you define a `Document` like this:

```
Dim pdfDoc As New Document()
```

You define a document with pages of size A4 and margins of 36 user units. If you don't want any margins, you need to create your document like this:

```
Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
```

When you create your `PdfPTable` like this:

```
Dim table As New PdfPTable(3)
```

You create a table that takes 80% of the available width. You can change this to 100% by adding this line:

```
table.WidthPercentage = 100
```

Or, if you want to specify a specific width, then you can use:

```
table.TotalWidth = 595f
table.LockedWidth = true
```

Note that `595` is the width (in *user units*) of an A4 page.

Borders are defined at the level of a `PdfPCell`:

```
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(phrase)
cell.BorderColor = BaseColor.RED
cell.BorderWidth = 3f
cell.Border = Rectangle.BOX
```

Of course, you can also define each border separately. That is explained here: [ITextSharp: Set table cell border color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9417054/itextsharp-set-table-cell-border-color)

In your case, you may want to define these properties for the `DefaultCell`. This way, you don't have to define them over and over again for each separate cell.

It would lead us too far if I would go into more detail (e.g. I could also talk about table events and cell events, for instance to draw dashed borders). Please download the free ebook [The Best iText Questions on StackOverflow](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html) where you will find the answers to some questions that are even less trivial than yours.